# You do not have sufficient access to your computer to connect to the selected printer

Tags: windows

I have a print server which runs on Windows 2003. When one of our domain user tries to connect to a particular printer from his XP machine, he gets the error message:

> You do not have sufficient access to your computer to connect to the selected printer

Couple of observations I have come across during troubleshooting.

1. User is able to connect few other printers on the same server
2. Other few set of users able to add this printer on their machines and able to print.
3. I have recreated the printer but still same error
4. I have renamed his profile on his machine but no luck
5. Checked the registry key HKCU\software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windows, it does exist.
6. The make and model of the printer is HP LaserJet P2050

Comment: And the make/model of the printers giving the problems are...?

Comment: I often suspect it has to do with the driver installing. We have been running into it and it's a PAIN IN THE @#%@!

Comment: It is HP Laster P2050 printer.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen this on a few...well, more than a few...systems on our network, and from what we can tell it's related to the driver being installed or updated on the client. We've been unable in some cases to find a suitable complete fix.

In some cases logging in as an administrator user and adding the printer works. Once the driver is installed as an administrator, it lets the user use it.

Another time we had to install the driver from the manufacturer's website to the client machine then try connecting to the share off the print server.

Last resort, we had to add the printer as a "local" IP printer.

It's been an enormously frustrating experience here. We even rebuilt the print server and re-added everything, but since moving to Win7 it seems to have gotten worse. There was a policy change made to allow users to install printers and it still hasn't seemed to help.

Comment: There are some differences in the Point and Print restrictions policies between [Server 2003/Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319939) and [Server 2008R2/Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2307161). It can be "fun" to manage multiple servers and client version simultaneous.